# How to view full SQLite BLOB?

Tags: sqlite, cakephp, cakephp-debug-kit

I'm studying the way Debug Kit stores data. I would like to see the full JSON of the content field, but it's obviously not displaying it in full. When running

```
sqlite3 -line debug_kit.sqlite "select content, length(content) from panels where panel='SqlLog';"
```

I see this:

[image]

As we can see, all results seem to be of the same length, ending with **{s:11:"** but their actual length differs. If I run

```
select length(content), content from requests join panels on panels.request_id = requests.id and panels.panel = 'SqlLog';
```

while I'm connected to its CLI, then I get this:

[image]

I'm not sure why this does not display the BLOB in full. I'm not an expert with SQLite, so if this is an easy question, please excuse me. Searched for the kind of issue I am having but I have not found a proper solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly-enough I solved this by writing a small PHP program of the like of

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('debug_kit.sqlite');
$stmt = $db->query("select content from panels where panel = 'SqlLog'");
while ($row = $stmt->fetchArray()) {
    echo var_dump($row);
}
```